# How to extract an image patch from a slice of NIFTI in R and save as png?

Tags: r, image, image-processing, png, nifti

I am trying to extract a 32x32 patch from a slice of 3d NIFTI image and save it as png. I am working in R. The NIFTI image contains 155 slices of 240x240 pixels. I have located the region of interest on the 63rd slice, but when I export it as png, the patch is saved as 480x480 pixels in size by default. 
The code is given below, where ROI is a 32x32 area from 58:89 on x position, 95:126 on y and on slice z=63.

```
library(oro.nifti)

set.seed(123)
arr = array(rnorm(240*240*155), dim = c(240,240,155)) 
img = oro.nifti::nifti(arr) #create NIFTI

png("C:/Users/Downloads/patchimg.png")
image(img[58:89, 95:126, 63], col=gray(0:64/64), xlab="", ylab="", axes=FALSE, useRaster=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

Is there another way to do it so the exported png is 32x32? Or is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62273259/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: see these links, I hope it's useful [link1](https://www.r-bloggers.com/working-with-nifti-images-in-r/), [link2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/oro.nifti/oro.nifti.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post!

Answer (score 0):

```
# --- Load libraries

require( imager )
require( ggplot2 )

# --- Get the area of interest as a data frame of x, y, value:

#  x y   value
#1 1 1 -0.4163
#2 2 1  0.2430
#3 3 1  1.4427
# ...

patch <- as.data.frame( as.cimg( arr[ 58:89, 95:126, 63 ]))

# --- Plot the patch with no legend, no axes, just bare

p <- ggplot( patch, aes( x, y ) )        +
     geom_raster( aes( fill = value ) )  +
     theme_void()                        +
     theme( legend.position = 'none' )

# --- Display the plot, if you wish
p
```

[image: The patch]

```
# --- Save the plot just created

ggsave(
    plot = p, filename = 'patch32x32.png'
  , height = 2, width = 2, dpi = 17
) 

# When I used dpi=16, the saved patch had dimensions 32x32, but when
# I opened it again using imager::load.image, it put a 1-pixel black
# border around perimeter.

# So, depending on what you are going to do with the saved patch,
# you might use dpi=16 or dpi=17.
#   2 inches high x 16 dots-per-inch ---> 32 dots high
#   2 inches wide x 16 dots-per-inch ---> 32 dots wide


im2 <- load.image( 'patch32x32.png' )
```

[image: Patch loaded and re-plotted]